# What is the difference between 0.0.0.0:1000 and *:1000 when calling UseUrls

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

In a .NET Core app, I am using:  `new WebHostBuilder().UseUrls("http://*:1234")`.

What is the effective difference between the code above and `new WebHostBuilder().UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:1234")`?

Comment: Not sure if there is a difference, but perhaps the latter is limited to the local broadcast domain, and the former is not?

Comment: It's hard to find a canonical source for this, but it appears that `0.0.0.0` is for IPv4 and `*` is for IPv6. You can see in the console output when using `*` that it reports that it's listening on `http://[::]:1234`, where `[::]` is the IPv6 wildcard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the docs related kestrel here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.1#url-prefixes

IPv4

> `0.0.0.0` is a special case that binds to all IPv4 addresses.

IPV6

> `[::]` is the IPv6 equivalent of IPv4 0.0.0.0.

Host name

> Host names, `*`, and `+`, aren't special. Anything not recognized as a
>   valid IP address or `localhost` binds to all IPv4 and IPv6 IPs. To bind
>   different host names to different ASP.NET Core apps on the same port,
>   use HTTP.sys or a reverse proxy server, such as IIS, Nginx, or Apache.

Host `localhost` name

> When `localhost` is specified, Kestrel attempts to bind to both IPv4 and
>   IPv6 loopback interfaces. If the requested port is in use by another
>   service on either loopback interface, Kestrel fails to start. If
>   either loopback interface is unavailable for any other reason (most
>   commonly because IPv6 isn't supported), Kestrel logs a warning.

Comment: So are you saying that http://*:1234 isn't recognized as a valid IP address and therefore binds to all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses?

Comment: the wildcard char `*` e.g. http://*:8081 (bind to any IP address or host)